# Closed form for $\prod_{j=1}^n\prod_{k=1}^{m_{j}-1} (x_j-kN^{-1})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, closed-form, products

Let $n,N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m_1,x_1,\ldots,m_n,x_n\in\mathbb{N}$. I'm trying to rewrite following expression

$$\prod_{j=1}^n\prod_{k=0}^{m_{j}-1} (x_j-kN^{-1})$$

I am only interested in the summands which have a factor $N^0=1$ or $N^{-1}$. So far I was able to calculate for any $j\in\{1,\ldots, n\}$:

$$\prod_{k=0}^{m_{j}-1} (x_j-kN^{-1})=x_j^{m_j}-N^{-1}\binom{m_j}{2}x_j^{m_j-1}+N^{-2}\cdot\ldots$$

Plugging this into the first product, I find

$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{j=1}^n\prod_{k=1}^{m_{j}-1} (x_j-kN^{-1})&=\prod_{j=1}^n\big(x_j^{m_j}-N^{-1}\binom{m_j}{2}x_j^{m_j-1}+N^{-2}\cdot\ldots\big)\\
&=\big(\prod_{j=1}^nx_j^{m_j}\big)-N^{-1}\big(\prod_{j=1}^nx_j^{m_j}\big)\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{m_j}{2}x_j^{-1}+N^{-2}\cdot\ldots
\end{align}$$

However, is it possible to rewrite the second expression into a nicer form?

$$\big(\prod_{j=1}^nx_j^{m_j}\big)\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{m_j}{2}x_j^{-1} =\  ?$$

Probably rewriting it with a factor $\big(\prod_{j=1}^nx_j^{m_j-1}\big)$, giving an equation like

$$\big(\prod_{j=1}^nx_j^{m_j}\big)\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{m_j}{2}x_j^{-1} = y\cdot \big(\prod_{j=1}^nx_j^{m_j-1}\big)$$

Unfortunately, I do not get any nice result for $y$ neither.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: FWIW, I don't think you can get something nicer without having more knowledge on $x_j$ or $m_j$.

Comment: I will work with the last equation, then. Thank you for your response!